# Laptop Thermal Sensor Reading Excessively High Temperatures

Tags: cooling, overheating, sensors

My laptop has done a thermal shutdown several times tonight due to high temperature readings. The computer however is not running at a temperature any higher than it normally does. I think the temperature sensor is malfunctioning and reading the temperature incorrectly. It is reading upwards of 250 degrees Fahrenheit but it is only warm to the touch. There is no way it is running this hot. Is there anyway to either get the sensor to read correctly or at least stop the emergency thermal shutdowns? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is this a Samsung, by any chance?

Comment: No, it's an HP laptop.

Comment: Just curious (my Samsung always did that). Under Windows 7, at least, you can do Power Options -> Plan Settings -> Advanced Power Settings -> System Cooling Policy and set it to I think "passive" or "inactive" or something like that, which should suppress thermal shutdowns. Use at your own risk, obviously...

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will try this and report back later.

Comment: yep, definitely looks like you are getting a bad reading from your ACPI sensors. can you confirm with CPUZ or speedfan?

Comment: It may actually be that hot, if the cpu fan is not spinning. The CPU die is quite small, and the sensor is internal.